# ... architecting & implementing help w/ Perl & REST

Tags: perl, rest

I really just need some basic software engineering architecting guidance... When I say 'architecting', I mean pseudo-code or statements I can go after in the Perl book I have, and hopefully some online examples...

I'm using Perl and I'm trying to parse Medline/Pubmed file paths on an Unix system in order to finally pass the PMID from each path to a pmid2doi conversion website (http://www.pmid2doi.org/).

The structure of each link is a filepath of the form...

```
/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/UNC00000000000042/00223468/v45i3/S0022346809003820
                                                |<-PMID->|
```

where `00223468` is the PMID.

```
$ ls
18507872 main.pdf main.raw main.xml
```

So far, I've got something that looks like this (in bash):

```
for doi in `find . -name "*.xml" | awk -F\/ '{print $2}' `  #this extracts the PMID
do
        echo  $doi
        wget pmid2doi website
done
```

Now I need help translating it to Perl.

The *pmid2doi* website requires inputting the PMID in order to get back the DOI.

This is what I need to get running in Perl, and I need a little help in designing implementing this...

Given your development background, I would be grateful for any insights, or recommended sites for generating regular expressions in Perl.

thanks very much!

Additionally:

I see that the *pmid2doi* website says the REST API expects the website *plus* the DOI value.
So I need to find some example Perl code that gets a REST value from a URL.
In REST I just prepare the URL as specified and then the returned result should be the value I want.

Comment: You can use the [`File::Find`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3A%3AFind) module for a recursive search (like find). Or just `glob` or `opendir` if recursion is not required. As for the rest of your question, I'm not sure I understand your input, or where you get it from.. or what you want as output.

Comment: break your problem down into smaller questions (ideally one at a time so you can apply things you've learned from one before asking the next), and show your best attempt in each question: first, finding the files in perl (hint: File::Find or glob()); second, extracting part of the filename (hint: File::Spec->splitdir); third, building the url; fourth, fetching the url (you already found LWP::Simple, it seems)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this maybe?

```
use File::Find;

my $client = REST::Client->new( $an_url );
File::Find::find( sub { 
        return unless m/\.xml$/;
        carp "Could not open $File::Find::name!" 
            unless open( my $fh, '<', $File::Find::name )
            ;
        my $doi;
        while ( <$fh> ) { 
            next unless ( $doi ) = m{[^/]*/([^/]*)};
            $client->GET( join( '/', $base, $doi ));
            do_stuff_with_content( $client->responseContent );
        }
        close $fh;
    } => '.'
);
```

Comment: might i use split to split strings by the "/" character and get the second piece: my $pmid = (split "/",$string,3)[1]

Comment: @user1769860, sure. I just saw no reason for "capturing" the part before the part you want. Thus the engine is just scanning the text until it gets to the part you want, pulls it and is done. 6 of one...

Answer (score 1):

Am I misunderstanding things, or could you just do this in Perl locally and not bother with the website? No need to hit up a remote host and deal with latency, usage limits, etc...

https://metacpan.org/module/Bio::DB::EUtilities

Edit: I am, that's a CGI client for NCBI. From the docs: 'A separate project, currently present in BioPerl-Run, utilizes the SOAP-based interface for eUtils.'

https://bitbucket.org/reece/docdepot/src/ca32360f6fa4/archive/perl-version/bin/doi-to-pmid

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# doi-to-pmid -- get the PubMed ids for a doi

use strict;
use warnings;

use Bio::DB::EUtilities;

my @pmids = doi_to_pmids( $ARGV[0] );
exit 1 unless (@pmids);
print( join("\n",@pmids), "\n" );

exit;


sub doi_to_pmids {
  my $doi = $_[0];
  my $f = Bio::DB::EUtilities->new(-eutil => 'esearch',
                                                                   -db => 'pubmed',
                                                                   -term => "$doi [doi]");
  my @ids = $f->get_ids();
  return (@ids);
}
```